# Tools for coordinating crons across users

Tags: linux, cron, multiple-users

I often find myself in a situation where I have several cron jobs that want to be run together and rely on certain jobs to be finished before they begin. If I'm running crons that require lots of computation, I use condor and dagman for managing the graph of dependencies, but for other more simple jobs, I have a custom python that implements a simple dag for handling the dependencies. How could do a similar thing across users? Both of these solutions rely on the jobs being run by a single user.

I find myself in a situation where one user is going to start producing some files and as some of those files become available, other users will start jobs. I could constantly poll to see if some output files are created, but maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger files - when job finishes, puts the trigger file to be picked up by other job! Remember about permissions as you need to remove trigger files.

Comment: Agreed that this is the best approach. If you need to do this across machines it is slightly more challenging but still feasible if you can arrange a shared filing system.